# How can I check my SSD without any OS installed?

Tags: ssd, check-disk

I have a laptop with no OS installed, I try to install Ubuntu but it seems to found an error and it can't be installed. I have make some other checks without errors, and now I want to check the SSD.

I have bought SSD for 3 months, so I don't think it should be bad but I want to discard any error on it.

EDITED: This is the error:

> [Errno30] read only file system '(path)' This is often due to a faulty
>   CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard disk. It may help to clean the
>   CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower speed, to clean the CD/DVD drive
>   lens (cleaning kits are available from electronics suppliers), to
>   check whether the hard disk is old and in need of replacement, or to
>   move the system to a cooler environment.

Comment: I don't know if I understood well, but basically you are trying to check if your SSD works or not? If so, you can externally connect it using a SATA to Dual USB 2.0. If what you are trying is install ubuntu on your SSD, that can be done even externally, and then installing ubuntu as you install it in a usb stick.

Comment: what error? tell us. Also any means "every" not "no" :D and also SSDs are not babies, they cant be called a 3 month old ssd lol .. say I have bought it for 3 months ...... You wanna discard it? dont do it .. just sell it to some crap buyers out there at least you can get back 10 dollers .................

Comment: Thanks for correct TechLife. I will try what you said Erlis D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Ultimate Boot CD](https://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) to boot from, together with a SATA-2-USB adapter and perform one of the various preinstalled HDD diagnostic tools.

1. Burn the bootable LiveCD *Ultimate Boot CD*. This way it doesn't matter if you have any OS installed.
   You need temporary access to a second PC to download & burn the [592 MB .ISO](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/linux/ubcd/ubcd533.iso)
2. Buy any SATA-2-USB adapter ([~$13 on amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HJZJI84), don't spent more) and use it to connect SSD and laptop. This way you ensure that your laptops storage controller doesn't cause the error

   Of course, as a first step, you could try it without that adapter. It seems your SSD is already installed as internal drive

   [image]
3. Boot *Ultimate Boot CD* from your laptop's CD drive and run one of the many preinstalled HDD checks tools

   [[image]

   <sup>Click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPm1W.gif)

   Here is a list of all HDD diagnostic tools

   [image]
4. Don't forget to test your memory and CPU too with [memtest86](http://www.memtest.org/) and [CPUstress test](https://github.com/Explorer09/cpustress-ubcd) which are both included into the LiveCD

Comment: LiveCDs thank you, saved my bacon and just keep saving my bacon how can I ever repay you ALL?